# How to make array of UILabels in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, uilabel

I tried this but got error !!!!

```
var lable : UILabel = [lable1, lable2, lable3]
```

// do stuff with label

Comment: `var lables: [UILable] = [...]`

Comment: Hello chrisz, I did same as u said -> var arrayOfUILable : [UILable] = [labl1, labl2, labl3] // **but error Use of unresolved indentifier labl1**

Comment: Hello chrisz sir, I found solution now I’m able to make array of it ..! Thanks for giving clue `for _ in 0..<7{ let lable = UILable.init(); arrayOfLable.append(lable)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, variable declarations follow this pattern:

```
var variable name: type = expression
```

You are saying that the type is a `UILabel`, while assigning it a list of `UILabels`.

Use `[UILabel]` as your type to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- The type is `UILabel` (typo)
- An array is indicated with a pair or square brackets `[]`

However the compiler can infer the type (and the variable is most likely a constant)

```
let lables = [lable1, lable2, lable3]
```

Comment: not working friend

Answer (score 0):

if you want mutable :

```
var labels = [xyz1, xyz2, xyz2]
```

and if you want immutable

```
let labels = [xyz1, xyz2, xyz3]
```

Comment: not working friend